# Is it possible to salvage messages from Weblogic JMS file store?

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have a couple of JMS file stores from a Weblogic 10.3 server, and i would like to retrieve the messages contained in them, if possible, without using Weblogic. Is this possible?

Many years ago i was able to read the JMS file store for a previous version of Weblogic using Java serialization (ObjectInputStream), but the files i have are giving me a

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: C001BEAD
```

exception when i open them using ObjectInputStream. I'm wondering if there is a file header that i need to skip before i can deserialize the messages, or perhaps this version of Weblogic doesn't use Java serialization at all.

The messages in the file are MapMessages. I can see the strings that correspond to the map keys, when i hex dump the file, but of course the values are not readable this way. But the fact that i can see the map keys make me hopeful that the messages are serialized in the file.

Any ideas on how to salvage the data?

Comment: BEA provides a utility - weblogic.store.Admin, which is able to dump the contents of the JMS queue files. Unfortunatly, in my case that isn't useful, because it simply dumps the contents of the messages in hex format - it doesn't expose the contents of the message in readable format. It might be useful if the messages were TextMessages, but in my case they're MapMesssages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way we and Oracle support were able to come up with, was to create another Weblogic instance configured the same way, and let that Weblogic instance pick up and process the messages.

Answer (score 2):

1. Set aside in a safe place all the *.dat files you wish to salvage.
2. Start-up a weblogic and log-in to the Admin console
3. Go to Home ->Summary of JMS Servers ->XL-JMS-Server
4. Enable “Insertion Paused At Startup”
5. Enable “Production Paused At Startup”
6. Enable “Consumption Paused At Startup” paused
7. Save the settings
8. Shutdown Weblogic
9. Swap-in a JMS data store you wish to salvage
10. Start Weblogic
11. Browse the JMS monitoring page to see which Queues and Topics have messages persisted.

At this point, the datastore is ready to be inspected/dumped using a QueueBrowser or a TopicSubscriber that you write. Alternatively, you could walk the messages ad hoc using Hermes JMS ( http://www.hermesjms.com ). Hermes has message renderers that you can implement for your custom message types.